# Why is animationDidStart called after removeAllAnimations is called?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, catextlayer

In `animationDidStart` (`CABasicAnimation` delegate), I want to update a `CATextLayer`. However, if the user touches the screen, I want to remove all the Animations that are going on by `[self.maskLayer removeAllAnimations];` (All my Animations are played sequentially).

However, after `removeAllAnimations`, somehow, `animationDidStart` AND `animationDidStop` are still called, the animation itself is NOT shown. This is NOT what I want, obviously.

The animations are added as follows:

```
- (void)addAnimations {

for (int i=1; i<6; i++) {
NSString* intValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];

animation.duration = 0.5;

animation.delegate = self;

animation.repeatCount = 0;

animation.autoreverses = NO;

[animation setValue:intValue forKey:@"animationString"];

animation.timingFunction = nil;

[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];

[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

animation.fromValue = (id) [self getCGRectForZoomLevel:i];

animation.toValue = (id) [self getCGRectForZoomLevel:i + 1 ];

animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + i * 2;

[self.shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:intValue];
}
}
```

How to prevent this? This issue has taken me several hours by now :(

thanks!

Comment: It is possible that one animation was triggered before the removeAllAnimation is called so the `didStart` method is called and after that the `didStop` method is called. You should check in this methods which animation triggered this methods (by checking `fromValue` `toValue` `byValue`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think so. I've set the beginTime property to some incremental values. Exactly those animations that are not yet run, still call their delegate after being removed, but they do NOT appear on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you starting new animations in `animationDidStop` ?

Comment: Nope. Only in animationDidStart I am updating another layer.

Comment: Anyone please? It should not be that hard, right?

Comment: @RudolfJ - Have you found an answer to this? I have the same issue which is causing a lot of sounds to play at once instead. I've had to use a boolean flag as a stop-gap - it works but this seems like a bug...